# Fields getting removed when updatating mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, date, save, php-mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB and I have stumbled over some update issues when using `Save()`.

When I click the save-button in my html-page I run the following code:

```
<?php
$action = (!empty($_POST['btn_submit']) &&
        ($_POST['btn_submit'] === 'Save')) ? 'save_article' : 'show_form';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
try {
    $mongodb = new Mongo();
    $articleCollection = $mongodb->myblogsite->articles;
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
    die('Failed to connect to MongoDB ' . $e->getMessage());
}
switch ($action) {
    case 'save_article':
      $article = array();
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $article['_id'] = new MongoId($id);
        } else {
            $article['_id'] = new MongoId();
        }
        $article['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $article['content'] = $_POST['content'];
        $article['tags'] = $_POST['tags'];

        if (!empty($id)) {
            $article['updated_at'] = new MongoDate();
        } else {
            $article['saved_at'] = new MongoDate();
        }

        $articleCollection->save($article);
        break;
    case 'show_form':
    default:
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $article = $articleCollection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
        }
}
?>
```

The idea is that if `$id` is not empty I update the document or else I insert.
I use `save()` to mange that.

I want two date-fields. One that hold the date the document was made and a new one for when it was last updated. 
The `“save_at”` can not be updated. The `“updated_at”` change every time an update is made. 
My problem now is that when I try to add the `“updated_at”` the `“save_at”` gets removed.
I also update the `“saved_at”`-field.

**My questions is:**

How do I insert an new field `('updated_at')` without removing the `“saved_at”`-field?

How do I keep the date in `“saved_at”`-field as it is without updating its value?

Answer (score 0):

use can done it with update command

$collection->update(array('id' => id),array('$set' => array('updated_at' =>$article['updated_at'])));